# What is the difference between Object.class and Object.class.inspect in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, class, oop

It seems like both of these methods return the same result (a human readable representation of the object and it's type). What is the differences between the methods?

```
class Foo

end

f = Foo.new
puts f.class          <==  puts Foo
puts f.class.inspect  <==  puts Foo
```

Comment: Can you clarify which *specific* part of the documentation of those methods you are having trouble with? That way, the Ruby developers can improve that part to help future readers.

Answer (score 4):

> It seems like both of these methods return the same result (a human readable representation of the object and it's type).

No, they don't.

> What is the differences between the methods?

[`Object#class`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-class) returns the class of the receiver.

[`Module#inspect`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-inspect) is an alias of [`Module#to_s`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-to_s) and returns a human-readable string representation of the module. In particular, it returns the [`Module#name`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-name) if it has one, and a unique representation otherwise. For singleton classes, it includes information about the object the singleton class is the singleton class of.

So, the two methods don't return the same result. In fact, they don't even return a result of the same class: `Object#class` returns an instance of the [`Class`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Class.html) class, `Module#inspect` returns an instance of the [`String`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html) class.

Answer (score 0):

Since `puts` needs a string, it calls the class's `to_s` method. I believe Class inherits the [method from Module](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-to_s):

> Returns a string representing this module or class. For basic classes and modules, this is the name. For singletons, we show information on the thing we’re attached to as well.
>
> *Also aliased as: [inspect](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-inspect)*

Perhaps you intended to look at the object's methods?

```
class Foo
  def initialize
    @t = 'Junk'
  end
end

f = Foo.new
puts f.class    # =>  Foo
puts f.to_s     # =>  #<Foo:0x007fce2503bbf0>
puts f.inspect  # =>  #<Foo:0x007fce2503bbf0 @t="Junk">
```